# SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate is called each time

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a my extension of SQLiteOpenHelper class. The code below.

```
    package com.Parapaparam.association;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "Associations";

    private static Context myContext;
    private static final String DB_NAME = "association.db"; 
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;    
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);  
        myContext = context;        
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.d(TAG, "- onCreate DB -");
        String text;           
        //InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.sql);
        try { 
            InputStream inStream = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.db);

            int size = inStream.available();

            // Read the entire asset into a local byte buffer.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inStream.read(buffer);
            inStream.close();

            // Convert the buffer into a string.
            text = new String(buffer);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Should never happen!         
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        String[] str = text.split(";");
            for (String s : str) { 
                Log.d(TAG, s);
                db.execSQL(s);           
            }
   }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And i have a class, which calls my DB.

```
public class DBInteraction {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;      


    public DBInteraction(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    private void openDB() {
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

Each time on my application start, DBHelper onCreate method are called. And I has an exception:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table associations 
already exists: CREATE TABLE associations (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_word 
INTEGER, association TEXT)
```

Why onCreate method calls each time when DB already created?

Why it happens?

Comment: It may be because of you might have done some changes in your previous DB and trying to open it again by overriding on the old one. Just delete the application from the device and try to run again.

Comment: @laalto In res/raw/db I have a sql dump of my db.

Comment: @Roc Yes, and there's no duplicate `create table associations` there?

Comment: @laalto No, there are not. My logcat Log.d(TAG, "- onCreate DB -");  tells that exactly onCreate is called each time.

Comment: @GrIsHu I tried this. Did not help.

Comment: `onCreate()` is called again because it never completes successfully (instead an exception is thrown). The question doesn't really have the information to figure out why is an exception thrown.

Comment: I solved this. Just changed my db's name. I deleted '.db' extension:

> private static final String DB_NAME = "association";

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After a few minutes looking for an answer I removed the entire db, executed the app again (then a new db was created) and after that I uploaded the db with all the data.

When I uploaded the good db I used the button "Push a file onto the device" in DDMS, not with drag&drop. I think this could be my problem, and could be yours too.